# Error: The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1)

Tags: c++, terminal, compiler-errors

I need help with VS Code errors and it's an issue with running a task with GCC and I've looked all over the internet and the only answers don't give instructions, so I'm left with an answer that doesn't tell me where to run the command, why the error happened, and how to avoid having this error occur in the future. Would be very grateful if someone could answer this question with explicit detail on how to fix this. Thanks.

I tried to run simple code, thought I could run the task no issue, got this error instead. Please help.

-Alexander

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for uploading pictures, I had no idea that was prohibited. Anyways, I found a solution which was just to delete the mingw64 and msys64 files from my C:\ disk. I reinstalled them from https://winlibs.com/ and it worked when I built it. So, exit code -1 still confuses me. I think I might have accidentally messed with the files responsible for running C++ code. Again, sorry for uploading pictures.

-Alexander